# Sorting an Arraylist? Treeset isn't working. Any other options?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to sort the contacts from my array into alphabetical order by last name (note: contacts are brought in by last name first "Brown and Adams" are the last names I'm testing. It seems my code treeset isn't working. Can anyone help me out?

```
    public void print() {
    // print the list
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
        String str;

        str = contacts.get(i).toString();
            set.add(str);


        for (String key : set) {
            System.out.println(key);

        }
    }
}
```

/*-------------- MY RUN ---------

Contact information has been saved.

brown, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf

adams, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf

---------------------------------/*

Comment: What about `Collections#sort`?

Comment: You are creating a new set on every iteration

Comment: So odd, this is the third question today with the same root problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong!

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
       set.add(contacts.get(i).toString());
}

for (String key : set) {
  System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfect. it's quite odd how I missed this. I've tried many things.

Comment: Even simpler, use "for each" syntax: `for (WhateverTypeThisIs contact : contacts) { set.add(contact.toString()); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Collections class...`Collections.sort(contacts);` unless if you wanna use your own code to assess your skills ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues, firstly you are creating a new TreeSet on each iteration of the loop that fills the set. Secondly you are calling a loop to print everything in the TreeSet (that you just made and put one thing in) on every iteration so essentially all you are doing is printing the array in the original order. Below is some code that fixes both of these issues:

```
public void print() {
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();

    // Fill up the TreeSet
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        String str = contacts.get(i).toString();
        set.add(str);
    }
    // Print out the TreeSet
    for (String key : set) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

}